# What difference does a positive / negative (do this, don't do this) slogan perspective make on the user's impression?

Tags: wording

On my app, the brief loading frame shows the logo, and below it a slogan. Lets say the slogan is a form of command such as **"Never create alone"**. Compare this with **"Always create together"**. Consider multiple similar slogan example pairs:

- **Don't wander**
- Find your way
- **Stop living small**
- Live big
- **Never forget**
- Always remember
- **Stop paying more**
- Start paying less

What difference does a positive / negative (do this, don't do this) perspective make on the user's impression?  In which situations might one be better than the other and vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

Either may be preferable, depending on your target audience... however, regardless of whether you choose positive or negative wording, there are other relevant content considerations. Here's some related marketing research on the topic of positive/negative words used in article headlines: https://blog.bufferapp.com/headline-strategies-psychology

For example, "start paying less" or "stop paying more" implies that money is a primary concern for your audience and a motivating factor for using the app. That may or may not be the case.

Research with potential users can help confirm what underlying needs might motivate them to use the app.

Examples:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/09/5-step-process-conducting-user-research/
& http://www.uie.com/articles/field_studies/

Once you have a clear definition of your target audience, it'll be easier to determine whether they're likely to be seeking information, inspiration, avoidance of problems (like spending too much money), etc.